# How to add Unirest to Magento 1.9.3.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, composer

I am trying to integrate [Prompt Cloud](https://www.promptcloud.com/promptcloud-api-documentation/) API with magento. For it the basic requirement is to install [Unirest](http://unirest.io/php.html) library. I am trying to install using composer:

```
composer require mashape/unirest-php
```

And then trying to call it in `head.phtml` as:

```
$headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
$query = array('foo' => 'hello', 'bar' => 'world');

$response = Unirest\Request::post('http://mockbin.com/request', $headers, $query);
```

But it is throwing error: `500 Internal server error`. When I have checked `system.log` file, it contains following errors:

> 2017-06-27T08:42:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Unirest\Request.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the composer autoloader (vendor/autoload.php) and register it before the Magento autoloader. That's important because the Magento autoloader will try to include the file where it expects the class to be which throws an error if that file does not exist. So later autoloaders do not have a chance at all.

There are some open source extensions that can do that for you, I can recommend https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader

## Configuration as per README:

> ### Magento Composer Autoloader
>
> You can also use this Extension to add the composer Autoloader.
>
> You need to configure the Path to your Vendor directory in your
> `<global/>`-node of local.xml:
>
> ```
> <composer_vendor_path><![CDATA[{{root_dir}}/vendor]]></composer_vendor_path>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have installed that extension by copying `app` directory to magento and in admin this extension is coming as enabled. Do I need to do something else because the problem is still the same?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani yes, it's explained in the readme section "Magento Composer Autoloader"

Comment: But I don't have vendor directory. And it also say to disable default autoloader. Is it necessary?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani that's impossible. If you successfully ran `composer require`, it created a `vendor` directory. Did you run that in the right directory?